# How do I a menu like the open menu from Gedit?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I am creating an application and would like to have a drop-down menu to search for files like the open menu in Gedit. What widgets do I need yo do this?

I have tried the menu widget and cannot find a way to get searching to work.

Note: I cannot find where in the Gedit source code the open menu is.

Comment: Could you share a sample code that works to better understand the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no widget provided by GTK out of the box to implement the gedit "Open" menu button:

[image: The gedit "Open" menu in its open state]

Gedit implements it inside its own code base, using a [`GtkMenuButton`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuButton.html) that opens a [`GtkPopover`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPopover.html) widget containing a [`GtkSearchEntry`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSearchEntry.html), for the input field used for search, and a [`GtkTreeView`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) for showing the search results. Plus, a [`GtkButton`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html) at the bottom to launch a [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) in order to select more files.

The tree view's model is populated using the recently used files list gathered from the default [`GtkRecentManager`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html); you can get a list of all recently used files and filter them by application name; after that, you can filter them with the contents of the search entry.

If you want to know more about how a GTK application is built you should use the [GTK inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector), which is provided by GTK itself as a debugging and development tool.